# How can I achieve the following layout in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

The thing I want to reach is something like this:

[image: goal image]

These are the main constraints I want to reach:

1. "text"-s being centered above the lower "button"-s and "thing2" being able to go in between "texts"-s when the screen is short enough.
2. I want the "button"-s to always be the same height/width (this is easily done by something like SizedBox) and the same distance from the top/bottom .
3. I want the "thing1" to be x height at max and scale with screen downwards if needed (either by making its texts smaller or making it scrollable, I haven't yet decided, this isn't the main problem).
4. I want "thing2" to always scale with screen.
5. When the screen is big enough, I want "thing1" and "thing2" to share the space between them evenly, and each being in the center of its own space.

Right now my layout is the following:

```
Column: MainAxisAlignment.SpaceBetween, height fixed
  Container: height fixed
    Row: MainAxisAlignment.SpaceBetween
      Button
      Button
  Container: height fixed
    thing1
  Container: height calculated based on screen height and other Containers' height
    thing2
  Container: height fixed
    Row: MainAxisAlignment.SpaceBetween
      Button
      Button
```

This is of course not all, I tried to include all relevant information about my layout without giving too much information pointlessly.

How would one go about adding the "text"-s above the "button"-s? (I tried Stack, but then I dont't know how to make them appear above the "button"-s while at the same time making "thing2" be above them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed achieve the things with this code (where MyBox is a simple widget with a colored container with width and height):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double buttonHeight = 35;
    const double buttonWidth = 100;
    const double textHeight = 40;
    const double textWidth = 30;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: buttonWidth,
              height: buttonHeight,
              child: MyBox(Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: buttonWidth,
              height: buttonHeight,
              child: MyBox(Colors.yellow),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: textWidth,
                    height: textHeight,
                    child: MyBox(Colors.green),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: buttonWidth,
                  height: buttonHeight,
                  child: MyBox(Colors.cyan),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: textWidth,
                    height: textHeight,
                    child: MyBox(Colors.indigo),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: buttonWidth,
                  height: buttonHeight,
                  child: MyBox(Colors.blue),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: buttonWidth,
              height: buttonHeight,
              child: MyBox(Colors.orange),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: buttonHeight,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: MyBox(Colors.purple),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: MyBox(Colors.brown),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

TLDR: I used a Stack widget to hold my other widgets, and Align widget to align (duh) my widgets in the Stack.
I used a Column to center my texts above my lower buttons. "mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end" was important so this column is at the bottom and not at the topside.
Finally I wrapped the Stack in a Padding.